# Make - "Treat warning as error" for specific files

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I'm currently working on a Makefile project, and since I'm using boost, I have tons of warnings during compilation, so I can't just enable `-Werror` in my entire build. However, I have a set of logging macros that effectively wrap `printf()` for me so I can have a prefix in all logging statements that includes line number, file base name, and a custom prefix.

I want to avoid potential bugs down the line, such as invalid logging statements which could potentially crash the software down the line (ie: a debug warning statement which seldom occurs causing a segfault).

Is it possible to pass an argument to `make` to have all instances of certain functions, or at least all macros defined in a header file, to treat warnings as errors?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can with

```
#pragma warning (error: 0001)
```

Where 0001 is the warning you want to be an error

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no standard, portable way to do this, so the solution will depend on your compiler.

With GCC you can use [Diagnostic Pragmas](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html).
For example `#pragma GCC diagnostic error "-Werror"` will enable Werror for the rest of the file.

Of course this is not portable, so if you use other compilers you'll want to wrap it in a `#ifdef __GNUC__`

Comment: Will this impact the entirety of files that include the header, or just for the macros and/or functions declared/defined within that header?

Comment: All the files including that header will also include the macro, so they'll be affected. An #include is really just a copy-paste operation. But note that you can enable `-Werror` only for some warnings with the syntax `-Werror=some-warning`, so it'd only trigger for the dangerous thing you care about.